# Add Result of CustomObject to title

Tags: powershell

I have a small script which reads out a registry path, creates an output as a PSCUstomObject and displays it in the console and also logs it into a file.

This is the script:

```
$LastLicense = 0

while ($true) 
{
    [int]$lizenzen = gp "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Logik GmbH\Logik\Execution" -name Licenses -ea Stop | 
    select -Expand Licenses

    if ($lizenzen -ne $LastLicense)
    {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            "DateTime" = (get-date).DateTime
            "Lizenzen in Gebrauch" = $lizenzen
        } | tee -FilePath C:\install\LizenzLog.txt -Append | ft -AutoSize
        $LastLicense = $lizenzen
    }
    sleep -s 10
}
```

Now the output is like this:

```
DateTime              Lizenzen in Gebrauch
--------              --------------------
2017.07.04 11:01:28                      5

DateTime              Lizenzen in Gebrauch
--------              --------------------
2017.07.04 11:01:28                      6

DateTime              Lizenzen in Gebrauch
--------              --------------------
2017.07.04 11:01:28                      5
```

but i'd like to have it like this:

```
DateTime              Lizenzen in Gebrauch
--------              --------------------
2017.07.04 11:01:28                      5
2017.07.04 11:01:28                      6
2017.07.04 11:01:28                      5
```

is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible Sir,You Should [PSCustomObject].DateTime   [PSCustomObject].'Lizenzen in Gebrauch' -tee -FilePath C:\install\LizenzLog.txt -Append ,Presently it is pushing the complete object.Rather than that Try to create a header ANd then Only Push the values into the files

Comment: Remove `| ft -AutoSize`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen well that's an easy solution :) thanks. Strange thing: the log also had the "strange" output, even though the `ft` was after the `tee`

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can skip `[pscustomobject]` creation and just create a strings which will be saved in CSV file:

```
#Create CSV file with Separator char for Excel and headers, if file exists will be replaced with empty one
"SEP=," | out-file -FilePath C:\install\LizenzLog.csv -Force
"DateTime" + "," + "Lizenzen in Gebrauch" | out-file -FilePath C:\install\LizenzLog.csv -Append

while ($true)
{
    [int]$lizenzen = gp "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Logik GmbH\Logik\Execution" -name Licenses -ea Stop | % Licenses
    if ($lizenzen -ne $LastLicense)
    {    #export values as string elements delimited by comma,  easy way to import to Excel (just open csv file it should open it corectly)
        "$((get-date).DateTime)"+ "," + $lizenzen | tee -FilePath C:\install\LizenzLog.csv -Append 
        $LastLicense = $lizenzen
    }
    sleep -s 10
}
```

by this you will get a CSV file ready to import to Excel - and if you just double click the columns should be imported at once.

after script execution if you want to see its presentation on console window
just import CSV: `Import-Csv C:\install\LizenzLog.csv`